# Cannot compile Microsoft COM/ActiveX example

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, activex

I am trying to compile the following COM/ActiveX example from Microsoft ([link to the source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdcxwbd5.aspx)), but I get some errors I cannot fix:

```
// evh_server.h
#pragma once

[dual, uuid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001")]
__interface IEvents {
    [id(1)] HRESULT MyEvent([in] int value);
};

[dual, uuid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002")]
__interface IEventSource {
    [id(1)] HRESULT FireEvent();
};

class DECLSPEC_UUID("530DF3AD-6936-3214-A83B-27B63C7997C4") CSource;


// evh_server.cpp
// compile with: /LD
// post-build command: Regsvr32.exe /s evh_server.dll
#define _ATL_ATTRIBUTES 1
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include "evh_server.h"

[module(dll, name = "EventSource", uuid = "6E46B59E-89C3-4c15-A6D8-B8A1CEC98830")];

[coclass, event_source(com), uuid("530DF3AD-6936-3214-A83B-27B63C7997C4")]     // <-- Error C3745: 'void VariantInit(VARIANTARG *)': only an event can be 'raised'
class CSource : public IEventSource {
public:
    __event __interface IEvents;      // <-- Error: interface types cannot be nested class types

    HRESULT FireEvent() {
        __raise MyEvent(123);         // <-- Error: identifier "MyEvent" is undefined
        return S_OK;
    }
};


// evh_client.cpp
// compile with: /link /OPT:NOREF
#define _ATL_ATTRIBUTES 1
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "evh_server.h"

[module(name = "EventReceiver")];

[event_receiver(com)]
class CReceiver {
public:
    HRESULT MyHandler1(int nValue) {
        printf_s("MyHandler1 was called with value %d.\n", nValue);
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT MyHandler2(int nValue) {
        printf_s("MyHandler2 was called with value %d.\n", nValue);
        return S_OK;
    }

    void HookEvent(IEventSource* pSource) {
        __hook(&IEvents::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler1);
        __hook(&IEvents::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler2);
    }

    void UnhookEvent(IEventSource* pSource) {
        __unhook(&IEvents::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler1);
        __unhook(&IEvents::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler2);
    }
};

int main() {
    // Create COM object
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    {
        IEventSource* pSource = 0;
        HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CSource), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IEventSource), (void **)&pSource);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            return -1;
        }

        // Create receiver and fire event
        CReceiver receiver;
        receiver.HookEvent(pSource);
        pSource->FireEvent();
        receiver.UnhookEvent(pSource);
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Another error:

> atlbase.h(2835): error C2338: 'CAtlDllModuleT' must be used with
>   either _WINDLL or _USRDLL defined

Since this code should be correct (I did not modify it), the problem could be in the way I am trying to build it.

Passing the options /LD and /link I get different errors (the option /OPT:NOREF is not recognized, and /link needs a source filename).

- Am I forced to generate a DLL?
- How can I build this project?
- Are those big numbers in the code really necessary?

---

Platform:  Microsoft Visual C++ 12.0

Comment: Did you check your project settings against http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235516(v=vs.60).aspx ?

Comment: @nikitoz - That article is about MFC DLL. What I am interested in is COM/ActiveX.

Comment: The sample intends the server and the client to go into two separate projects - one creating a COM DLL, and the other a console application to exercise it. Witness `[module(dll, ...)]` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code, which is shuffled into single source code file (console application):

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#define _ATL_ATTRIBUTES 1
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

[dual, uuid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001")]
__interface IEvents 
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT MyEvent([in] int value);
};

[dual, uuid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002")]
__interface IEventSource 
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT FireEvent();
};

class DECLSPEC_UUID("530DF3AD-6936-3214-A83B-27B63C7997C4") CSource;

[coclass, event_source(com), uuid("530DF3AD-6936-3214-A83B-27B63C7997C4")]
class CSource : public IEventSource
{
public:
    __event __interface IEvents; 

    HRESULT FireEvent() 
    {
        __raise MyEvent(123);
        return S_OK;
    }
};

[event_receiver(com)]
class CReceiver 
{
public:
    HRESULT MyHandler1(int nValue) 
    {
        printf_s("MyHandler1 was called with value %d.\n", nValue);
        return S_OK;
    }
    HRESULT MyHandler2(int nValue) 
    {
        printf_s("MyHandler2 was called with value %d.\n", nValue);
        return S_OK;
    }
    void HookEvent(IEventSource* pSource) 
    {
        __hook(&IEvents::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler1);
        __hook(&IEvents::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler2);
    }
    void UnhookEvent(IEventSource* pSource) 
    {
        __unhook(&IEvents::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler1);
        __unhook(&IEvents::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler2);
    }
};

[ module(type=exe, name="Event") ];

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Create COM object
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    {
        CComObject<CSource>* pSource = NULL;
        ATLVERIFY(SUCCEEDED(CComObject<CSource>::CreateInstance(&pSource)));
        CComPtr<IEventSource> pEventSource = pSource;
        CReceiver Receiver;
        Receiver.HookEvent(pEventSource);
        pSource->FireEvent();
        Receiver.UnhookEvent(pEventSource);
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can get it there ([SVN](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/ComEventAttribute/), [Trac](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/ComEventAttribute)) with VS2012 project files.

Comment: It works! Just a minor issue: even if the code builds and runs correctly, in the IDE I have two "IntelliSense" errors: on the line `__event __interface IEvents;` I have: "interface types cannot be nested class types"; on the line `__raise MyEvent(123);` I have: "identifier "MyEvent" is undefined". It looks like an issue with IntelliSense not being aligned with the new compiler's features, e.g. ignoring that a signal does not have an implementation. Am I right?

Comment: I would say that Intellisense is treating this `__event __interface...` properly. Note that these are not "new" features exactly. These are dead end old but but still supported features. I personally did like the concept, but apparently Microsoft at some point dropped that.